# How can db owner grant select permission on other users table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

all.
I have the following problem with postgresql.

I have a database "dwh" with schema "sa".

I have a user "dwa" who is the owner of database "dwh".

```
select pg_get_userbyid(datdba) dbowner
from pg_database where datname='dwh';
-- dwa
```

Another user "user1" created table "table1" in schema "sa".

Now when I'm trying (as "dwa") to grant permission to select from table1 I get an error:

```
grant select on sa.table1 to dwa;
```

> [42501] ERROR: permission denied for table table1

Can user "dwa" (db owner) grant permission to select from table1 and how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `GRANT` privileges on an object you need to fulfill at least one of three conditions:

- you are a superuser
- you own the object (or are a member of the role that owns it)
- you have been granted the privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Ownership of the database doesn't give you any privileges on objects within the database!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run as `user1` owner of schema `sa` and table `table1`:

```
grant usage on schema sa to dwa;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema sa to dwa with grant option;
```

But it is unusual to grant privilege to oneself.

Comment: Yep, I have done like you said. But I thought that "dba" user (database owner) has a possibility to grant permission to all tables in db, but as Laurenz Albe said it is not true.